# Hive UDTF - unable to fetch field names via getFieldName, it is returning _col0,_col1

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am working on Hive UDTF to transpose each row around primary key. as part of requirement, i need to associate column name and corresponding data with the key.

```
e.g.
Source Data

Customer_id    Customer_name     Customer_type
1000000        ABCD              Individual
```

Hive UDTF will convert the data into following

```
Key          att_name          att_val
10000000     customer_name     ABCD
10000000     customer_type     Individual
```

i have written the udtf and it is working and currently producing below data

```
Key          att_name       att_val
10000000     _col0          ABCD
10000000     _col1          Individual
```

here is the code in which `(StructField)inputFields.get(i)).getFieldName()` is returning _col0 instead of customer_name.

could this be a probable defect in apache hive or there is yet another mapping for _col0 to actual schema that i should refer to.

```
public class transposeUDTF extends GenericUDTF {

private Map tableMap = new HashMap();
private MetadataListStructObjectInspector metadataDetails;

@Override
public StructObjectInspector initialize(StructObjectInspector args) throws UDFArgumentException {

    List inputFields = args.getAllStructFieldRefs();
    ((StructObjectInspector)args).getTypeName();

    for(int i = 0; i < inputFields.size(); ++i)
    {
        tableMap.put(i+1,((StructField)inputFields.get(i)).getFieldName());

    }

    return super.initialize(args);

}

@Override
public StructObjectInspector initialize(ObjectInspector[] argOIs) throws UDFArgumentException {
    List<String> fieldNames = new ArrayList<String>(3);
    List<ObjectInspector> fieldOIs = new ArrayList<ObjectInspector>(3);
    fieldNames.add("key");
    fieldNames.add("AttrName");
    fieldNames.add("AttrVal");
    fieldOIs.add(PrimitiveObjectInspectorFactory.javaStringObjectInspector);
    fieldOIs.add(PrimitiveObjectInspectorFactory.javaStringObjectInspector);
    fieldOIs.add(PrimitiveObjectInspectorFactory.javaStringObjectInspector);
    return ObjectInspectorFactory.getStandardStructObjectInspector(fieldNames, fieldOIs);
}

@Override
public void process(Object[] record) throws HiveException {

    ArrayList<Object[]> results = new ArrayList<Object[]>();

    for(int i = 1; i < record.length; ++i) {
        results.add(new Object[] {record[0],tableMap.get(i).toString(),record[i]});
    }

    Iterator<Object[]> it = results.iterator();

    while (it.hasNext()){
        Object[] r = it.next();
        forward(r);
    }
}

@Override
public void close() throws HiveException {
    // do nothing
}
}
```

Comment: please refer https://github.com/cloudera/RecordServiceClient/blob/master/java/hive/src/main/java/com/cloudera/recordservice/hive/RecordServiceObjectInspector.java

Comment: upon further research, i found out that hive changes column names from actual name to column internal name using getColumnInternalName present inside HiveConf class. is there a way through which we can control this.